# Interpret pointer as a two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array transpose function that mirrors arrays like so:

```
[1][2][3]            [1][4][7]
[4][5][6]    ===>    [2][5][8]
[7][8][9]            [3][6][9]
```

Here is the concept of the algorithm I came up:

```
size_t numvars = variables.size(), numsegs = segments.size();

for (int v = 0; v < numvars; ++v) {
  for (int s = 0; s < numsegs; ++s) {
    float * row = in + (s * numvars);
    out[v][s] = *(row + v);
  }
}
```

When proceeding through the algorithm by hand, all works as expected.  I would like to implement the function such that it takes two pointers to two-dimensional arrays, one with the source array and the second to a memory buffer that will hold the transposed array.  When I try to implement the algorithm in C++ in a function I get the following error:

```
void transposeArray(float * in, float * out) throw()
{
  size_t numvars = variables.size(), numsegs = segments.size();

  for (int v = 0; v < numvars; ++v) {
    for (int s = 0; s < numsegs; ++s) {
      float * row = in + (s * numvars);
      out[v][s] = *(row + v);
    }
  }
}
```

> out[v][s] = *(row + v); 
>   invalid types ‘float[int]’ for array subscript

Is this because the compiler does not know that it should treat the second `float * out` as a 2-dimensional array?  If so, what's the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `out` variable is a pointer to a `float`, so derefencing it in `out[v]` yields a float value. And you can't subscript a float value.

What you need to do, is to calculate the array index for the `out` 2D array the same way you calculated it for the `in` 2D array:

```
void transposeArray(float * in, float * out) throw() {
  size_t numvars = variables.size(), numsegs = segments.size();

  for (int v = 0; v < numvars; ++v) {
    for (int s = 0; s < numsegs; ++s) {
      out[v*numsegs + s] = in[s*numvars + v];
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note:
It's a pity that you are apparently writing this code in C++, and not in C. Because in C, you can do this in a quite nice way:

```
void transposeArray(int numvars, int numsegs, float (*in)[numvars], float (*out)[numsegs]) {
  for (int v = 0; v < numvars; ++v) {
    for (int s = 0; s < numsegs; ++s) {
      out[v][s] = in[s][v];
    }
  }
}
```

The trick here is that the `in` and `out` arguments are declared to be pointers to line arrays, which allows the language to invoke the same pointer arithmetic magic that it uses when you declare an array with `float myArray[numvars][numsegs];`. This pointer arithmetic boils down to do the same thing implicitly which `v*numsegs + s` does explicitly.

The advantage of C is, that it allows for array types with *run time sizes*, something C++ does not do. Of course, if `numvars` and `numsegs` are compile time constants, you can do the equivalent in C++.

Here is how you can write your function if you want to use the same function signature as the one you gave in the question:

```
void transposeArray(float * in, float * out) throw() {
  size_t numvars = variables.size(), numsegs = segments.size();
  float (*in2D)[numvars] = (void*)in;
  float (*out2D)[numsegs] = (void*)out;

  for (int v = 0; v < numvars; ++v) {
    for (int s = 0; s < numsegs; ++s) {
      out2D[v][s] = in2D[s][v];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I originally had `*(out + (v*numsegs) + s)` and then realized your use was much cleaner: `out[v*numsegs + s]` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know the dimensions of the array.

So if you keep your simple pointers then you need to do the same addressing arithmetic for `out` as you currently do for `in`.

Namely, calculate a row pointer, use an offset into that row, instead of `out[v][s]`.

---

Technically,

- the expression `out[v]` produces a reference to a `float`, and
- if the float is denoted *f*, the expression *f*`[s]` is then just invalid: you can't index a `float` value.

---

As general advice, unless you're using some framework that uses `float` everywhere, such as SFML, then just use `double`. That's the default floating point type in C and C++. E.g., the literal `3.14` is of type `double`, not `float`.